# how to set vertical position of progress dialog

Tags: android

I have a progress Dailog in my code. I want to set its position before the last component (button) vertically. Please tell how can I do that?

**Code**

```
progDailog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        //progDailog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progDailog.setCancelable(false);
        progDailog = new ProgressDialog(activity,R.style.MyTheme);
        progDailog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        progDailog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        progDailog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked perfectly.

```
progDailog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```